# OpenLdap invalid structural object class chain

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to load an ldif file into an OpenLdap instance which is running in a container:

```
docker run --env LDAP_ORGANISATION="jboss" --env LDAP_DOMAIN="jboss.com" --env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="admin" --detach osixia/openldap
```

Now I'm trying to upload with a UI the following ldif file which used to work on the container-less installation of OpenLdap:

```
dn: dc=jboss,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
dc: jboss
o: MCC
dn: ou=People,dc=jboss,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
dn: uid=admin,ou=People,dc=jboss,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: uidObject
objectclass: person
uid: admin
cn: Manager
sn: Manager
userPassword: secret
dn: ou=Roles,dc=jboss,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Roles
dn: cn=Manager,ou=Roles,dc=jboss,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: Manager
description: the JBossAS7 group
member: uid=admin,ou=People,dc=jboss,dc=com
```

As a result, the following exception is raised on the last line:

```
LDAP: error code 65 - invalid structural object class chain (organization/organizationalUnit)]; remaining name 'cn=Manager,ou=Roles,dc=jboss,dc=com'
```

If appears it's failing to add the group Manager to whom the user admin belongs. Can you spot any error in the ldif file ?
Thanks!

Comment: Your LDIF file isn't valid. You need a blank line after each entry.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a carriage return before each "dn:" and now it worked.